# npm installing wrong version

Tags: npm, kendo-ui, npm-install, package.json

I am having an error where npm is installing the incorrect version of a package.

Here is the line that is within my package.json:

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "2.4.1"
```

I have deleted the `package-lock.json` file to ensure that versions are used from my `package.json`.

---

Then I run `npm install` with the following result:

```
npm WARN @progress/kendo-angular-popup@1.3.4 requires a peer of rxjs@^5 <5.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I am so confused! Also, Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Maybe some other dependency of your project depends on version `1.3.4` of `@progress/kendo-angular-popup`. You can run `npm ls @progress/kendo-angular-popup` to see the dependency tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a warning that you need a higher version of angular for the kendo-angular-popup dependency to work.  Version 5 or higher.